# UPDATED: Using COALESCE / IFNULL to filter recursive cte query

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have an issue with filtering / adding a condition to a recursive CTE query to avoid NULL result. The recursive part of query stops looping once it comes across a gap in the descending series of gids taken from the first non-recursive query (essentially when the `x.t_gid = s.g2_t_gid` filter in the `WHERE` is NULL).

**x.t_gid and s.g2_t_gid are decsending series' of integers, and x.t_gid(n) = s.g2_t_gid(n+1).**  There are meant to be gaps in the series of gids but I want the recursive part to just continue onto the next row if it returns a NULL result.  See code below.

```
WITH RECURSIVE snapped_points(t_gid, r_rdname, r_gid, r_ufi, snapped_geom, snapped_distance, g2_t_gid, g2_r_rdname, s_g2_snapped_geom, route_distance) AS (

(SELECT t_gid, 
    r_rdname,
    r_gid,
    r_ufi,
    snapped_geom AS snapped_geom,
    snapped_distance,
    g2_t_gid,
    g2_r_rdname,
    g2_snapped_geom AS s_g2_snapped_geom,
    route_distance
FROM x_joined_snapped x
LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT x.t_gid, 
    x.r_rdname,
    x.r_gid,
    x.r_ufi,
    x.snapped_geom,
    x.snapped_distance,
    x.g2_t_gid,
    x.g2_r_rdname,
    x.g2_snapped_geom,
    x.route_distance
FROM snapped_points s
INNER JOIN x_joined_snapped x
ON x.t_gid <> s.t_gid
AND (x.t_gid = s.g2_t_gid AND x.snapped_geom = s.s_g2_snapped_geom)
--OR (x.t_gid < s.g2_t_gid),  <-- difference between 1s and 24s**
LIMIT 1
)
)
SELECT  t_gid, r_gid, r_ufi, r_rdname, snapped_distance, snapped_geom FROM snapped_points
;
```

**What I am aiming to achieve.**

1. From the array of potential snapped points for t_gid(n), choose the row where distance between snapped_geom(n) and g2_snapped_geom(n) is the shortest.  If there is only 1 result choose that.
2. From the array of potential snapped points for t_gid(n-1) (which equals
   g2_t_gid(n)), select the subset containing only g2_snapped_geom(n) chosen in the previous step.
3. From this subset, choose the row where distance between snapped_geom(n-1) and g2_snapped_geom(n-1) is shortest. If there is only 1 choose that. Append to previous result. Loop until you run out of rows.

Once the recursive part hits a gap in the table where `x.t_gid <> s.g2_t_gid` it just stops looping.  I have been able to fix this by adding a `OR x.t_gid < s.g2_t_gid` to the `WHERE` clause, but this increases the compute time from 1000ms to 24,000ms.

I have tried using COALESCE but can't get it to work, and recursive CTE queries don't allow the recursive part to be repeated in the query.

I am a complete noob so I'm sure this code could be made prettier and more efficient. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had a hard time trying to understand your issue and I failed. Where's the recursive CTE ? Show how you execute it. We only have half the code needed to understand here. Also you have LIMIT clauses without ORDER BY clause, sounds weird. In the second query you should use *explicit syntax* for your JOIN between s and x, that would be clearer

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks for having a look.  I have amended code and post in line with your comments and added more context.  Let me know if you need any further background. Cheers

Comment: `ON x.t_gid <> s.t_gid,` <<-- what is this comma doing there ? Should that be an `AND` ?

Comment: Hi thanks, now added your comment, changed , to AND.